# Using equality comparison in Ruby Sequel library's "having" block

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am trying to construct a SQL "having" clause via Sequel, in Ruby (Ruby 2.5.7, Sequel 5.28.0), but having issues with using an equality comparison.

All of the documentation and examples show that constructing a having block works for operators like `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=`. However, `=` throws a `SyntaxError`.

If I construct a `having` statement using `>`, I get the SQL out correctly:

```
query.having do sum(Sequel.case({{column => nil} => 1}, 0)) > count.function.* end
=> #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM \"schema\".\"table\" GROUP BY \"id\" HAVING (sum((CASE WHEN (\"column\" IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) > count(*))">
```

But if I change that `>` to `=`, I get a `SyntaxError`:

```
query.having do sum(Sequel.case({{column => nil} => 1}, 0)) = count.function.* end
SyntaxError: unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
...nil} => 1}, 0)) = count.function.* end
...                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
... 1}, 0)) = count.function.* end
...                            ^~~
```

What is a valid `=` operator in this case? I can't find mention in the Sequel documentation or specs that show this usage. If I've missed this, apologies, and am happy to re-read if someone points me to where that information is.

`==` and `<=>` both lead to undesired and inaccurate SQL, and I also can't hack it via a combination of `<=` and `>=` since the `having` block doesn't seem to recognize `&&` as and-ing multiple conditions (it just takes the last condition).

```
query.having do sum(Sequel.case({{column => nil} => 1}, 0)) == count.function.* end
=> #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM \"schema\".\"table\" GROUP BY \"id\" HAVING false">

query.having do sum(Sequel.case({{column => nil} => 1}, 0)) <=> count.function.* end
=> #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM \"schema\".\"table\" GROUP BY \"id\" HAVING false">

query.having do sum(Sequel.case({{column => nil} => 1}, 0)) >= count.function.* && sum(Sequel.case({{column => nil} => 1}, 0)) <= count.function.* end
=> #<Sequel::Postgres::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM \"schema\".\"table\" GROUP BY \"id\" HAVING (sum((CASE WHEN (\"column\" IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) <= count(*))">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/sequel-talk/c/5vieXjhpEV0), this should work, wrapping it in a virtual row and using a hash with `=>`

```rb
query.having do 
  { sum(Sequel.case({{column => nil} => 1}, 0)) => count.function.* }
end
```

or using `=~`

```rb
query.having do 
  sum(Sequel.case({{column => nil} =~ 1}, 0)) == count.function.* 
end
```